# Google Maps APi Key in phpajaxsql_v3

Tags: php, sql, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[google maps phpsqlajax_v3 page](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3.html)

I am creating an app for mobile devices.  Part of the app gets lat/long info from database and shows on the map, it works similar to what you see above.

I read that I must have a API key to use maps, and also I do plan to release a paid version along with a free version, I would need a commercial api key too.

Now my question,  by looking through the source code on the link above,  where would I insert my api key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use the V3 for google map then see this

> Note: This version of the Google Maps JavaScript API no longer needs API keys!

and as google declare google map v2

> Google Maps JavaScript API V2 (Deprecated)

if you use this then see this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABCDEFG"></script>
```

here in the above script you have to pass the map key

if you developing application for mobile application please specify the more about that like for android, iphone etc. and specify appropriate tag with the question

Comment: Im using v3 so thats ideal for me, thanks.   I Will be developing for iOS to begin with, then move along to Android I will be using PhoneGap for development.   So its fairly easy to code up once for all devices...   On the PAID version, i have extra features (which is not google maps related)  would I need a Maps Premier Api key for that?  Or not?

Answer (score 1):

In Google Map version 3, there is no api key needed. See documentation:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/

And before going for a paid version [see this](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#usagelimits).